# ESLint - How to restrict property of `this`

Tags: javascript, eslint

To prohibit code like `this.$log`.

The following config doesn't work:

```js
{
  'no-restricted-properties': [
    2,
    {
      object: 'this',
      property: '$log',
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [no-restricted-syntax](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax) rule.

So in your `.eslintrc` file add this rule.

```
"no-restricted-syntax": [
    "error",
    {
        "selector": "MemberExpression[object.type='ThisExpression'][property.name='$log']",
        "message": "this.$log is prohibited"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, could your please answer this similar question as well? It's bugging me for a really time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65434989/eslint-vue-how-to-disallow-log-usage-in-the-following-places

Comment: With your inspiration, I finally got this working, thank you, Sir! https://stackoverflow.com/a/65453967/7881859