# How to ban console log in the Vue template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

Origin of `$log`:

```js
Vue.prototype.$log = console.log
```

Places to be banned:

```html
<template>
  <!-- Place 1 -->
  <div @click="$log">
    <!-- Place 2 -->
    {{ $log }}
    <!-- Place 3 -->
    {{ $log('foo') }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'

// Place 4
Vue.prototype.$log('foo')

export default {
  created() {
    // Place 5
    this.$log('foo')
  },
}
</script>
```

Some additional information that might help:

- [ESLint - How to restrict property of `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65432897/eslint-how-to-restrict-property-of-this)
- [no-restricted-syntax](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax)
- [vue/no-restricted-syntax](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-restricted-syntax.html)

Comment: To clarify, you mean how to get eslint to flag `$log` as not allowed, not how to disable the call of that function. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @apokryfos Yes, the goal is to ban all $log usages.

Comment: @apokryfos I've got it working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging into `no-restricted-syntax`, `vue/no-restricted-syntax` rules, and `AST`s, I finally got this working, here're the working rules:

```js
{
  rules: {
    'no-restricted-syntax': [
      'error',
      {
        selector: '[name=$log]',
        message: "Using '$log' is not allowed.",
      },
    ],
    'vue/no-restricted-syntax': [
      'error',
      {
        selector: '[name=$log]',
        message: "Using '$log' is not allowed.",
      },
    ],
  },
}
```